# can we have less code for validation form in laravel if i have more than 20 inputs

Tags: php, database, laravel, validation

if i have more than 20 fields,can we validate this with less code???
i do not want to write required for all input .

```
$request->validate([
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'gender' => 'required',
        'date_of_birth' => 'required',
        'place_of_birth' => 'required',
        'nationality' => 'required',
        'mobile_number' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:informations',
        'home_region' => 'required',
        'digital_address' => 'required',
        'school_name' => 'required',
        'school_region' => 'required',
        'school_digital_address' => 'required',
        'school_level' => 'required',
        'school_program_of_study' => 'required',
        'patron_first_name' => 'required',
        'patron_last_name' => 'required',
        'patron_gender' => 'required',
        'patron_mobile_number' => 'required'


    ]);
```

Comment: as is working code, this is more suited to codereviews SE - but I have a feeling it wouldn't be on-topic there either

Comment: This is just 20 lines of code that automatically checks everything for you as opposed to you writing all of the validation code, making sure it works, testing, etc... How much easier can it get?

Answer (score -1):

That's the minimal code laravel needs to works the validation.

If you dont enter each field's name, how is it supposed to know wich missing entry from the request is required ? laravel needs each and every input name marked down.

Answer (score -1):

Actually yes there is a way.

This is your code

```
$request->validate([
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'gender' => 'required',
        'date_of_birth' => 'required',
        'place_of_birth' => 'required',
        'nationality' => 'required',
        'mobile_number' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:informations',
        'home_region' => 'required',
        'digital_address' => 'required',
        'school_name' => 'required',
        'school_region' => 'required',
        'school_digital_address' => 'required',
        'school_level' => 'required',
        'school_program_of_study' => 'required',
        'patron_first_name' => 'required',
        'patron_last_name' => 'required',
        'patron_gender' => 'required',
        'patron_mobile_number' => 'required'
    ]);
```

Now in your form html for all these fields you need to make an array for it like this

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="person[first_name]">
    <input type="text" name="person[last_name]">
    <input type="email" name="email">
</form>
```

and in your Controller or Request you can make this array required like this

```
$request->validate([
    'person' => 'required|array',
    'person.*' => 'required'
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:informations',
]);
```

This way you can have less index in your array ;), Hope it will help

Comment: How would the validator know that `person.first_name` is required and not `person.last_name` is required ?!

Comment: Don't you see @N69S in my validator I have maked it as an array

Comment: I see, but witch attribute of that array is `required` ? how many of them are required ? how do you know that an attribute is missing from the desired ones ?

Comment: it's for all, all the elements of the Array (person) is required. To summarize ```php    'person.*' => 'required'    ``` Check the asterisk sign just after the array name

Comment: let's say that in the form i remove/disable the input name `first_name` so it's not sent in the query, will your validator check for it ? will it return `first_name required` ?